# what is wrong with regex_match? very simple expression

Tags: c++, regex, std

I'm using VS2010 and coding c++ console application and faced the problem

```
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

//...

if (!regex_match("abab",regex("(ab?)*")))
{
  //the problem is - why we are here? why it doesn't match?
}
```

checked here http://regexpal.com/ - it matches

Comment: Many implementations of the regular expression library are sketchy, especially in VS 2010. Keep in mind that VS 2010 is **not** a C++11 compiler, it simply supports _some_ C++11 features.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious you're right!! I test it in VS2012, that's way the regex matched for me.

Comment: [Works with gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65f607082de2cc06).

Comment: If you're using VS and just getting started/familiar with C++11 I suggest referencing the list of [features each version of the compiler supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368(v=vs.110).aspx). This will at least give you a good idea of what features you are limited to and the amount of support provided by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple: regex_match only returns true if the entire sequence gets matched.  You may want to use regex_search if you want to see if a string contains your regex.

<del>"ab?" matches "aba", the repeater ("()*")make this match once.  The remainder is "b", so it's not a full match.</del>

I'm sorry, I misread the regex.  It should be a full match.  Weird enough:

```
regex_match("aab", regex("(ab?)*")) == true
```

Seems to be a bug within the stl used (tested with QT Creator 2010.05, makespec = VS2010).  Replacing regex_match with regex_search in your code matches right, but the match_results are empty - indicating something still goes wrong.

With VS2012 all tests matched correctly.